# Relative URL to absolute in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I need to turn relative URLs returned by Paperclip into absolute in controller. My solution for this:

```
 root_url.chomp('/') + record.photo.url(:large)
```

Since this task is applicable not only to Paperclip I would like to know if there's a better way of doing it that doesn't involve any hardcoded values.

There's a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695393/rails-building-an-absolute-url-in-a-models-virtual-attribute-without-url-helpe), but none of the solutions from it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first example from the linked post should work for you, works for me anyway.

```
record.photo.url(:large, :host => request.host)
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, it returns the same relative URL.